# Android audio streaming is not working on samsung devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am working on online radio app, i am using media player for audio streaming. it's working fine with almost all the devices but it's streaming on Samsung s3/s4/s5/s6/s7 Devices. here is my code

```
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(str_url);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What do you have in your logs? And which kind of url are you trying to stream from? (a static one?)

Comment: ya it's a static one, and in log is  08-28 09:18:17.969: WARN/MediaPlayer(7100): info/warning (703, 0)

08-28 09:18:17.969: WARN/MediaPlayer(7100): info/warning (701, 0)

08-28 09:18:17.969: INFO/MediaPlayer(7100): Info (703,0)

08-28 09:18:17.979: INFO/MediaPlayer(7100): Info (701,0)